# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{n}=b$, then evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right)^{a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis

> I have to calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right)^{a_n}$$ if $\frac{a_n}{n} \rightarrow a,$ and $\frac{b_n}{n} \rightarrow b$, for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $a_n, b_n$ positive sequences.

By Stolz-Cesàro theorem
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(n+1)-n} \rightarrow a, \quad n \rightarrow \infty$$
where $\{n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is monotone and divergent. Also, $b_{n+1}-b_n \rightarrow b, n \rightarrow \infty$ but I can't go further

Comment: I think you cannot evaluate this limit. The rate at which $(\frac {b_{n+1}} {n+1}) / (\frac {b_n} {n})$ tends to $1$ comes into the picture.

Comment: What we can say if $a_n=(-1)^n$?

Comment: A complete answer is this: The limit may or may not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $a_n \log(\frac {b_{n+1}} {b_n})$. write this as $(a_n /n) n [\log (\frac {b_{n+1}} {n+1}) -\log (\frac {b_n} n) +\log (\frac n {n+1})]$. From this it is clear that limit of $n$ times $[\log (\frac {b_{n+1}} {n+1})-\log (\frac {b_n} n)]$ is needed to evaluate this limit. This cannot be determined by the given hypothesis. Of course this limit may not even exist.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$ a_n=b_n=n+(-1)^n. $$
For $n=2k$,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac {b_{2k+1}}{b_{2k}}\right)^{a_{2k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac {(2k+1)-1}{2k+1}\right)^{2k+1}=\frac1{e}. $$ 
For $n=2k+1$,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac {b_{2k+2}}{b_{2k+1}}\right)^{a_{2k+1}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac {(2k+2)+1}{(2k+1)-1}\right)^{2k}=e^3. $$ 
Thus there is no way to obtain $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right)^{a_n}$.